# Libreoffice: Get adress range from cell

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm not sure what the correct terms would be, so I can't effectively search for a possibly already answered question, but here it comes:

I'm looking for a way to have in cell A1 a formula (lets say SUM) with the content of the cells [B1] and [C1] as *part* of the range.

So if B1 contains the text "5" and C1 contains the text 7, A1 should be the SUM of the cells D5 to D7.

You know what I mean…? Like in this pseudocode:

A1 = D{B1}:D{C1}.

I know there is an indirect function, but I cant wrap my head around how to use it in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the indirect funtion with CONCAT(), since B1 and C1 don't contain a full cell reference but only a part of it. You need to add the missing part "D" using CONCAT().

In your use case, the formula to put in A1 has to look as follows:

> `=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCAT("D";B1)):INDIRECT(CONCAT("D";C1)))`

Here's the structure as shown in the function wizard:

[image: INDIRECT with CONCAT - Function Wizard]

And here's my complete sheet with example values:

[image: INDIRECT with CONCAT - Sheet]

Comment: This can be shortened to `=SUM(INDIRECT("D"&B1&":D"&C1))`.

Comment: @JimK - you're right, just add another answer, i would give +1 :-)